# How to scale fonts in UWP XAML app based on resolution scaling using "resource system"

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

The [documentation for FontSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.fontsize#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_FontSize) indicates that you can using different font sizes for different scalings using "the resource system." Unfortunately, it does not elaborate on how one would do that or what exactly it means by "the resource system."

I have seen some guidance on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041883/font-size-scaling-in-windows-store-universal-app-w8-1-wp8-1) stackoverflow question, but that appears to use converters to solve the problem.

Is there another, better, way to do this using "the resource system?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value type of `FontSize` is double. so you could make double type resource dictionary.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Double x:Key="SmallFontSize">20</x:Double>
        <x:Double x:Key="BigFontSize">40</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**For usage**

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource SmallFontSize}" Text="Something"><TextBlock>
```

For dynamically change a FontSize resource value for UWP. Please refer this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50341584/7254781).